# Modify Macro to put vlookup results in empty column for next month

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automate a monthly report that I run.  Each month, I run a query (embedded into a separate tab) and then use vlookup to move the values into the column for the current month.

I want to create a macro to move the values for the current month, but what I need to figure out, is how to modify the macro to check if a column for a month has been filled out, and if it is, then to put the monthly numbers in the column to the right (next month).  I have been researching this for a while, but I have very little VBA experience and get stuck when I run into errors.  I know I can use the "IsEmpty" function, but I'm not sure of the best way to use it.

Here is a copy of the Macro:

```
 Range("N6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-10],'ENT - Query Totals'!C2:C4,3,FALSE)"
Range("N6").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
Range("N6").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N6:N82"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("N6:N82").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-60
Range("N6:N82").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("O64").Select
Cells.Replace What:="#N/A", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

So basically, I want to check if "N6" is empty.  If it is, the macro  would use vlookup to move the data from the query tab into the column "N".  If it is not empty, I want it to copy the data from the query tab into column "O", etc.

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated while I continue to learn VBA

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim copyRange as Range
Dim rowNum As Long

Range("N6").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-10],'ENT - Query Totals'!C2:C4,3,FALSE)"
Range("N6").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N6:N82"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Set copyRange = Range("N6:N82").Select
rowNum = 64

For each cell in copyRange
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("O" & rowNum) Then
        cell.copy destination:=Range("O" & rowNum)
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
    Else
        cell.copy Destination:=Range("N" & rowNums)
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
    End if
Next cell
```

i feel like this is somewhere in the neighborhood of what youre asking but the way you worded your problem is a little confusing to me